# How to add data attribute for options_from_collection_for_select in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider this as my select tag

```
<%= select_tag "post[brand_slug]", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'slug', 'name'), prompt: 'select' %>
```

This works fine but I need a data attribute

```
<%= select_tag "post[brand_slug]", options_from_collection_for_select(@products, 'slug', 'name'), data: {id: @products.id} , prompt: 'select' %>
```

`@product.id` is not working. How can I get the `ID` too

Answer (score 71):

Try following:

```
<%= select_tag "post[brand_slug]", options_for_select(@products.map{ |product| [product.name, product.slug, { 'data-id' => product.id }] }), prompt: 'select' %>
```