# 4 Drop down menus, update each one based on the selection before to SEARCH

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am creating a cinema application in Ruby on Rails and am currently working on the bookings.

What I am trying to do is implement a search so that a user can search for a free seat, select that seat, and then book that seat for a film's showing.

To do this, I want to implement 4 drop down menus: films, showings, screens and seats. But the difficulty is that what I want is the drop down menus to be dynamic and update themselves based on the previous selection, so when a user selects a film, the showing drop down only shows showings for that film, when the showing is selected the screen drop down only shows the screen that showing is in, and then the screen drop down menu is used so that the seats drop down only shows seats that are in that screen.

I have so far enabled the user to search for a screen and then when they click search the seats available are shown on the seats/index.html.erb.

This was done using the partial _booking_lookup.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag my_path, :method=>'post', :multipart => true do %>

<%= select_tag ('screen_id'), 
    options_from_collection_for_select(@screens, :id, :screens_info, 0 ),
    :prompt => "Screen" %> 


<%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Which is displayed on the layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= render(:partial => '/booking_lookup', :locals=> {:film => @films = Film.all, :showings => @showings = Showing.all, :screens => @screens = Screen.all, :seats => @seats = Seat.all, :my_path => '/seats/display_seats_by_screen' }) %>
```

And links to the `display_seats_by_screen` in the seats_controller:

```
    def display_seats_by_screen
    @seats = Seat.screen_search(params[:screen_id])
    if @seats.empty?
        # assign a warning message to the flash hash to be displayed in
        # the div "feedback-top"
        flash.now[:alert] = "There are no films of that genre."
        # return all products, in alphabetical order
        @seats = Seat.all
    end
    render :action => "index"
end
```

Which uses the `screen_search` in the seat.rb model:

```
def self.screen_search(search_string)
    self.where("screen_id = ?", search_string)
end
```

So essentially for the above before the user selects the screen they should have selected a showing and before that a film so that only screens for that showing are shown so they can select an appropriate seat.

The models associations: film:

```
has_many :showings
belongs_to :certificate
belongs_to :category
```

showing:

```
belongs_to :film
has_many :bookings
belongs_to :screen
```

screen:

```
has_many :seats
```

seat:

```
belongs_to :screen
has_many :bookings
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you planning to handle the race condition for someone grabbing a seat before the other can finish a transaction?

Comment: No, only one person will be on the system at a time for the moment

Comment: One way would be using javascript: the **films** dropdown data attributes will contain each option's related **shows**, and based on that option pick, and using the data-attribute for that pick- you will show the relevant **shows**.

Another way would be using an ajax. when the user pick a **film**, send a request to back server containing his **film** choice. base on that, find the relevant **shows**, return that information, and build the next dropdown, (the **shows** dropdown) based on that given information

Comment: Can you share the relationship between the models: Film, Screen, Seats, Showing, it's pretty self explanatory, but just in case.

Comment: I think the java seems more appropriate as I'm guessing Ajax requires the page to reload when I just want the drop down menus to update. Without sending me to another website because I have looked at so many, can you please spell it out to me how I can do this?

Comment: Ajax won't require the whole page to reload. anyway, I'll try to create a small example in jsfiddle.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh I have added in the models

Comment: Ok, I didn't finish it, But this is the main idea: http://jsfiddle.net/x1jeaarc/1/.

Of course you need to set it dynamically but It shouldn't be too hard

Comment: Thank you, I don't know enough about java to get the second one to update though? Also where would I put the java? In the application.js?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1jeaarc/3/):

It works on the first one, It's not dynamic though.
html:

```
<p>films</p>
<div data-film1='["showing1_value","showing2_value"]' data-film2='["showing3_value","showing4_value"]'> 
    <select name="user[films]" id="films" class="select"><option value=""></option>
        <option value="film1">transformers</option>
        <option value="film2">the hangover</option>
    </select>
</div>   
<p>showing</p>    
<div data-showing1='["screen1_value","screen2_value"]' data-showing2='["screen3_value","screen4_value"]'> 
    <select name="user[showing]" id="showing" class="select">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="showing1_value">showing1</option>
        <option value="showing2_value">showing2</option> 
        <option value="showing3_value">showing3</option> 
        <option value="showing4_value">showing4</option> 
</select>
</div>
```

js:

```
 $('#films').change(function(){

     if ($("#films").val() == "film1"){
         //you can get this films shows:
         alert (   $("#films").parent().data("film1")   );
         //now you need to ajust the showing dropdown according: something like this:
         $("#showing").html('<option value=""></option>');

         $.each( $("#films").parent().data("film1"), function( index, show ){
            $("#showing").append('<option value="' + show + '">' + show + '</option>');
         });
     }    
});
```

Since the js only apply to this current page, I wouldn't put it in application.js (where it would be includes on every page), I would put it on the relevant page- since it only apply that page.

On the server side you would need to set the data attributes of course.

What I did was put each film's showings, as [data attributes](http://bit.ly/1zU50UW), and then when the user, selected that film, I used that film's attributes- which contains that film's relevant showings, to create the next dropdown, as seen [here](http://bit.ly/1zU5B9j)

Now for the rails part:

In this page controller action,
You will have something like this:

```
#now it doesn't matter how you do it, you can choose your own way
#but eventually you need like seen here, only that it includes all the films,
#and for each film all his showings.

@films = Film.all

@film_data_attributes_string = ""

@films.each do |film|
  film_str = "data-#{film.title}="                   #this should give: data-tranformers=
  part_two_1 = "'[\""                                  #this should give '[\"


  film_showings_array = film.showings                          #this will give the film's showins. since film has_many :showings, 
  showings_array_names = film_showings_array.map(&:name)       #this will give an array of the showing's titles
  part_two_2 = showings_array_names.join('","')                #this should give a string:    showing3_value","showing4_value




  part_two_3 = "\"]'"                                  #this should give "]'

  @film_data_attributes_string << film_str + part_two_1 + part_two_2 + part_two_3 + " "

  #all together:          data-tranformers='["showing1_value","showing2_value"]' 
  #notice there is a space in the end
end
```

this will give you (more or less) the [data attributes of the films](http://bit.ly/1zU907X). It's not tested, but that's the main idea.
assuming both your films and showings have an attributes called "name".
(of course it would be better to move all that functionality to the film model and not use that in controller)

Then in the view, you will use @film_data_attributes_string of course, maybe you will need to use html escape or something, not sure.

Or you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817452/how-to-add-data-attribute-for-options-from-collection-for-select-in-rails)

and use this instead:

```
@data_hash = {}
@films.each do |film|
  @data_hash["data-#{film.title}"] = film.showings.map(&:name).to_json
end
```

You will need to do something similar for the java script.

Comment: Ok, I can get that working purely by copying and pasting but its hard coded in the films and showings, how can I get it to display the films and showings from the database?

Comment: I get that, but what happens when I add more showings? Would I have to add in the new showings?

Comment: Thanks, sorry but I'm still pretty confused. If I'm updating the showings drop down for the film shouldn't it go in showings_controller? And my films table has the column name title rather than name, and the showings table links to the films table by having the film_id, rather than the film name. I don't know what to change the javascript to, and still don't fully understand what happens when I add a new showing because surely rather than having `<option value>` these will need to be updated?

Comment: You have all those 4 dropdowns on the same page.
Now I don't know which controller action, you use for showing that page- because you left that part out. But your page must use a controller action- in that action is where the rails code in my answer should be, i'll update the answer to match your title attribute.

Comment: you need to add the data-attributes to your select field,
take a look at [how-to-add-data-attribute-for-options-from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20817452/how-to-add-data-attribute-for-options-from-collection-for-select-in-rails). 

though for this method the string I have created wouldn't work